# How to watch a file in a state but do not throw an error if file does not exists?

Tags: salt-stack

I've got a state which creates a file:

```
/my/file/path:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://salt/file/path
```

And I've got a service which I want to reload once this file will be created/modified

```
my-service:
  service.running:
    - enable: True
    - watch:
      - file: /my/file/path
      - file: /some/other/file/one
      - file: /some/other/file/two
      - file: /some/other/file/three
```

This one works fine in case first state is executed, but the problem is that first state is executed only conditionally. So whenever it is NOT executed I'm getting an error

> ```
>   Result: False
> ```

```
 Comment: The following requisites were not found:
                             watch:
                                 file: /my/file/path
```

Is any of these solutions possible

1. keep current code: watch /my/file/path  on service but don't worry if file not exists and DO NOT reload a service in such a case
2. When creating a file, please reload 'my-service'. But if file already exists and has not changed do not reload

Seems to be simple use-case and I'm almost sure it's easy to achieve, went through salt docs couple of times but still cannot get my head around it

Appreciate any help

Comment: `service.running` is a state module, and it will not always result in reloaded service if service is already running. You will need to use an [execution module](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.service.html#module-salt.modules.service).

Comment: @seshadri_c incorrect. The `watch` function will trigger a restart or reload - https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.service.html#salt.states.service.mod_watch

Answer (score 0):

Saltstack requisites require the named requisite to be present in the compiled states. Since the `/my/file/path` state is executed conditionally, it may not always be present during execution.

One option could be to reload the service also with the same condition, while "listening" for changes to the file. Something like below:

```yaml
{% if condition == "met" %}
create-and-restart:
  file.managed:
    - name: /my/file/path
    - source: salt://salt/file/path

  module.run:
    - service.restart:
        - name: my-service
    - onchanges:
        - file: create-and-restart
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to clear a common point of confusion, Salt's `watch` **does not watch files**, it watches states. `file: /my/file/path` refers to a state using the `file` module with the name or id that matches `/my/file/path`.

To solve your specific problem, you just need to move the requisite definition to the conditional state:

```yaml
/my/file/path:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://salt/file/path
    - watch_in:
      - service: my-service
```

The service state will then watch the file state, if and only if the file state is included in the current highstate.

Comment: We could even use `listen` and `listen_in` combination as the question has multiple states that may end up reporting changed, and the restart can be done once at the end of the Salt run.